# How can I find the Git commit that added a specific Gradle build dependency across file renames and reorderings?

Tags: git, git-bisect

I'm working in a multi-project [Gradle](https://gradle.org) project implemented using [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) and Java, and version controlled using [Git](https://git-scm.com).  One of the subprojects depends on a particular library (let's call it `com.example:mylib`), declared in that particular subproject's `build.gradle` file.  This library was added a while back, and I would like to find the commit that added it so I can get some context to why it was added, and whether it's still needed.  There are no imports in my code for the library, but since Spring Boot's [auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-auto-configuration) works in part based on which libraries are on the classpath, the absense of direct usage within my code is not sufficient to determine whether or how the library is used.

To add a wrinkle to this scenario, various project restructurings have happened since the start of the project: subprojects have been renamed, moved to child projects, etc. multiple times.  The build files themselves have been restructured and reordered as well.  Additionally, the Gradle files have switched from [Groovy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_build_script_primer.html) (`build.gradle`) to [Kotlin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (`build.gradle.kts`) and then back again.

**build.gradle**

```groovy
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.example:mylib'
    // ...
}
// ...
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation("com.example:mylib:1.0.5")
    // ...
}
// ...
```

I know of a few manual ways I could trace back and find the change.  For instance, I could use [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) and work my way back through the changes to the line, manually switching files as the renames and restructurings happen.  But these approaches can be a bit time consuming and tedious when there have been a lot of changes.

How can I quickly and easily find the commit that added the library?

Comment: Try `git log -S "com.example:mylib"`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I'll expand that into a full answer unless you'd like to do so.

Comment: @ElpieKay You can add `--reverse` to get the first time the reference showed up at the top.  Or to get clever and show only the first time the reference showed up, you could do `git log -S nimbusds --pretty=format:"%H" | tail -1 | xargs git log -1`.

Comment: It's okay. If it works, please feel free to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) can be used to quickly find the change in an automated fashion.

Given that `develop` has the library dependency, and `abc123` is a commit before the library dependency was added, the following will find the commit that added the dependency:

```
git bisect start
git bisect new develop
git bisect old abc123
echo "! grep -rI --include \*.gradle\* mylib ." > /tmp/bisect.sh 
chmod u+x /tmp/bisect.sh 
git bisect run /tmp/bisect.sh
git bisect reset
```

[`git bisect start`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_basic_bisect_commands_start_bad_good) starts a new bisect session.  We then need to identify at least one one old and one new commit — that is to say, one commit before the change ("old") and one commit after the change ("new").  `git bisect new develop` specifies `develop` as a "new" commit, and `git bisect old abc123` specifies "abc123" as an "old" commit.  (Note that the standard terminology is bad/good, not new/old, but as this is more of a change than a breakage, I'm choosing to use the [alternate terms](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_alternate_terms) "old" & "new" instead of the standard terms.)

Git will then employ a binary search algorithm, switching to a commit roughly halfway through the old & new commits.

**output:**

```
Bisecting: 818 revisions left to test after this (roughly 10 steps)
[1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef12345678] Committed some stuff
```

At this point, you could manually identify this commit as old or new (`git bisect old`/`git bisect new`), with Git binary searching its way to the commit that introduces the change.  However, we can automate this process by having Git check each potential commit with a script by using [`git bisect run <scriptname.sh>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_run).  If the script returns with exit code 0, it's identified as "old"; if it exists with a code between 1 and 127 (other than 125), it's "new".

For this case, we can use the command `grep -rI --include \*.gradle\* mylib .`.  This uses [grep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) to recursively find any non-binary files that match the pattern `*.gradle*` containing the term "mylib".  This will match `build.gradle` and `build.gradle.kts`, but skip many other files that we don't care about (thus speeding up the process).

However, the grep command returns the opposite exit code that we want.  It returns a successful ("old") response on a match, but we want it to be a failure ("new") response.  The command can be negated to the desired value by using the [!](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02_01) reserved word: `! grep -rI --include \*.gradle\* mylib .`.

This command is stored to the `/tmp/bisect.sh` script and made executable:

```bash
echo "! grep -rI --include \*.gradle\* mylib ." > /tmp/bisect.sh 
chmod u+x /tmp/bisect.sh
```

Now that we have the script, we pass it to `git bisect run` to get the commit where the dependency was added:

```bash
git bisect run /tmp/bisect.sh
```

**output:**

```
abcdefg1234567890abcdefg1234567890abcdef is the first new commit
commit abcdefg1234567890abcdefg1234567890abcdef
Author: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
Date:   Tue May 26 17:37:25 2020 -0400

    adding a new library for fun and profit
    
    1. add the library
    2. ???
    3. profit

 subproject1/build.gradle                           |   6 +-
 .../nested/subpackage/MyAwesomeClass.java          |  37 -------
 .../nested/subpackage/LessAwesomeClass.java        | 118 +++++++++++++++++++++
 .../nested/BoilerplateJunk.java                    |  32 ++++--
 subproject1/src/main/resources/application.yaml    |  12 +++
 .../another/subpackage/Whatever.java               |  28 +++++
 6 files changed, 189 insertions(+), 44 deletions(-)
```

Finally, we call [`git bisect reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_reset) to end the bisect session and change back to the branch we were on before we started the bisect session.

Answer (score 1):

[`git log -S`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt) displays only the revisions the number of appearance a given text string appears.  The last item in the list will be the revision the text string was first added.  In the case of the library, this will be the dependency it was first added (assuming the build file is the only location the dependency has ever appeared).

```bash
git log -S myLib
```

> **`-S<string>`**
>
> Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for the scripter’s use.
>
> It is useful when you’re looking for an exact block of code (like a struct), and want to know the history of that block since it first came into being: use the feature iteratively to feed the interesting block in the preimage back into `-S`, and keep going until you get the very first version of the block.
>
> Binary files are searched as well.

If you want to output just the revision the dependency was first added, this can be done with some command piping.  One way to do this is:

```bash
git log -S mylib --pretty=format:"%H" | tail -1 | xargs git log -1 --stat
```

**output:**

```
commit abcdefg1234567890abcdefg1234567890abcdef
Author: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
Date:   Tue May 26 17:37:25 2020 -0400

    adding a new library for fun and profit
    
    1. add the library
    2. ???
    3. profit

 subproject1/build.gradle                           |   6 +-
 .../nested/subpackage/MyAwesomeClass.java          |  37 -------
 .../nested/subpackage/LessAwesomeClass.java        | 118 +++++++++++++++++++++
 .../nested/BoilerplateJunk.java                    |  32 ++++--
 subproject1/src/main/resources/application.yaml    |  12 +++
 .../another/subpackage/Whatever.java               |  28 +++++
 6 files changed, 189 insertions(+), 44 deletions(-)
```